# Folding SVG envelope with css animation behaves strange when targeting one SVG layer

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I want to animate my SVG envelope so that the flap folds downwards. How can i achieve this?

I have tried to animate the whole envelope and i think this is the way the flap should behave. See the result:

```css
#svg-envelope {
  height: 200px;
  animation: fold 4s forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes fold {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg-envelope" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1715 1689" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.5;">
  <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-382.933,-901.191)">
      <g id="base" transform="matrix(0.885663,0,0,1,121.31,324.647)">
          <rect x="302.051" y="1266.63" width="1922.47" height="994.035" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);stroke:black;stroke-width:8.82px;"/>
      </g>
      <g id="innerside-after" transform="matrix(0.885663,5.76867e-17,1.24618e-16,-1.0038,121.31,2868.06)">
          <path d="M1238.5,755.873C1253.69,747.587 1272.88,747.587 1288.08,755.873C1438.68,838.015 2224.52,1266.63 2224.52,1266.63L302.051,1266.63C302.051,1266.63 1087.89,838.015 1238.5,755.873Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear3);stroke:black;stroke-width:8.8px;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:1;"/>
      </g>
      <g id="bottomflap" transform="matrix(0.885663,5.42038e-16,-4.3385e-16,1.10652,121.31,1183.76)">
          <path d="M1236.74,756.832C1252.76,748.097 1273.82,748.097 1289.83,756.832C1444.69,841.292 2224.52,1266.63 2224.52,1266.63L302.051,1266.63C302.051,1266.63 1081.89,841.292 1236.74,756.832Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear4);stroke:black;stroke-width:8.32px;"/>
      </g>
      <g id="topflap-open-colored" transform="matrix(0.885663,4.72789e-16,-6.19857e-16,1.30832,121.31,-65.8757)">
          <path d="M1233.71,758.485C1250.98,749.068 1275.6,749.068 1292.86,758.485C1454.58,846.686 2224.52,1266.63 2224.52,1266.63L302.051,1266.63C302.051,1266.63 1072,846.686 1233.71,758.485Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear7);stroke:black;stroke-width:7.46px;"/>
      </g>
  </g>
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,994.035,302.051,1763.65)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(59,183,90);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:rgb(31,93,81);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(21,62,78);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear2" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,524.276,302.051,1004.49)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(226,226,226);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(25,65,80);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear3" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,263.844,302.051,870.864)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(226,226,226);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(25,65,80);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear4" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,524.276,302.051,1004.49)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(59,183,90);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:rgb(31,93,81);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(21,62,78);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear5" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,263.844,302.051,870.864)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(226,226,226);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(25,65,80);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear6" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,524.276,302.051,1004.49)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(59,183,90);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:rgb(31,93,81);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(21,62,78);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear7" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,524.276,302.051,1004.49)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(59,183,90);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:rgb(31,93,81);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(21,62,78);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

But when i try to apply the same animation to only the flap-layer (see below), it's seems like it's a little zoomed (or stretched?) and it doesn't start from its original starting point. Why is that? And how can i solve this?

```css
#svg-envelope{
  height: 200px;
}

#topflap-open-colored{
  animation: fold 4s forwards infinite;
}
    
@keyframes fold {
  0%{
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
  }

  100%{
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg-envelope" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1715 1689" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.5;">
  <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-382.933,-901.191)">
      <g id="base" transform="matrix(0.885663,0,0,1,121.31,324.647)">
          <rect x="302.051" y="1266.63" width="1922.47" height="994.035" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);stroke:black;stroke-width:8.82px;"/>
      </g>
      <g id="innerside-after" transform="matrix(0.885663,5.76867e-17,1.24618e-16,-1.0038,121.31,2868.06)">
          <path d="M1238.5,755.873C1253.69,747.587 1272.88,747.587 1288.08,755.873C1438.68,838.015 2224.52,1266.63 2224.52,1266.63L302.051,1266.63C302.051,1266.63 1087.89,838.015 1238.5,755.873Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear3);stroke:black;stroke-width:8.8px;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:1;"/>
      </g>
      <g id="bottomflap" transform="matrix(0.885663,5.42038e-16,-4.3385e-16,1.10652,121.31,1183.76)">
          <path d="M1236.74,756.832C1252.76,748.097 1273.82,748.097 1289.83,756.832C1444.69,841.292 2224.52,1266.63 2224.52,1266.63L302.051,1266.63C302.051,1266.63 1081.89,841.292 1236.74,756.832Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear4);stroke:black;stroke-width:8.32px;"/>
      </g>
      <g id="topflap-open-colored" transform="matrix(0.885663,4.72789e-16,-6.19857e-16,1.30832,121.31,-65.8757)">
          <path d="M1233.71,758.485C1250.98,749.068 1275.6,749.068 1292.86,758.485C1454.58,846.686 2224.52,1266.63 2224.52,1266.63L302.051,1266.63C302.051,1266.63 1072,846.686 1233.71,758.485Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear7);stroke:black;stroke-width:7.46px;"/>
      </g>
  </g>
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,994.035,302.051,1763.65)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(59,183,90);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:rgb(31,93,81);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(21,62,78);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear2" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,524.276,302.051,1004.49)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(226,226,226);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(25,65,80);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear3" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,263.844,302.051,870.864)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(226,226,226);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(25,65,80);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear4" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,524.276,302.051,1004.49)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(59,183,90);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:rgb(31,93,81);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(21,62,78);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear5" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,263.844,302.051,870.864)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(226,226,226);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(25,65,80);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear6" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,524.276,302.051,1004.49)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(59,183,90);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:rgb(31,93,81);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(21,62,78);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear7" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,524.276,302.051,1004.49)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(59,183,90);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:rgb(31,93,81);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(21,62,78);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're running into was that you had a `transform` attribute on the `#topflap-open-colored` element that was conflicting. By moving that property to the path inside it, that issue was resolved.

Unfortunately, setting the `transform-origin` to `bottom` on the group didn't quite finish the job. It seems that the various transformations were causing the origin point to be somewhat below the perceived bottom of the envelope flap. I was able to adjust the origin slightly to improve the result—I landed at 94% after some trial and error:

```css
#svg-envelope{
  height: 200px;
}

#topflap-open-colored {
  transform-origin: center 94%;
  animation: fold 4s forwards infinite;
}
    
@keyframes fold {
  0%{
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }

  100%{
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg-envelope" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1715 1689" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.5;">
  <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-382.933,-901.191)">
      <g id="base" transform="matrix(0.885663,0,0,1,121.31,324.647)">
          <rect x="302.051" y="1266.63" width="1922.47" height="994.035" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);stroke:black;stroke-width:8.82px;"/>
      </g>
      <g id="innerside-after" transform="matrix(0.885663,5.76867e-17,1.24618e-16,-1.0038,121.31,2868.06)">
          <path d="M1238.5,755.873C1253.69,747.587 1272.88,747.587 1288.08,755.873C1438.68,838.015 2224.52,1266.63 2224.52,1266.63L302.051,1266.63C302.051,1266.63 1087.89,838.015 1238.5,755.873Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear3);stroke:black;stroke-width:8.8px;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:1;"/>
      </g>
      <g id="bottomflap" transform="matrix(0.885663,5.42038e-16,-4.3385e-16,1.10652,121.31,1183.76)">
          <path d="M1236.74,756.832C1252.76,748.097 1273.82,748.097 1289.83,756.832C1444.69,841.292 2224.52,1266.63 2224.52,1266.63L302.051,1266.63C302.051,1266.63 1081.89,841.292 1236.74,756.832Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear4);stroke:black;stroke-width:8.32px;"/>
      </g>
      <g id="topflap-open-colored">
          <path d="M1233.71,758.485C1250.98,749.068 1275.6,749.068 1292.86,758.485C1454.58,846.686 2224.52,1266.63 2224.52,1266.63L302.051,1266.63C302.051,1266.63 1072,846.686 1233.71,758.485Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear7);stroke:black;stroke-width:7.46px;" transform="matrix(0.885663,4.72789e-16,-6.19857e-16,1.30832,121.31,-65.8757)"/>
      </g>
  </g>
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,994.035,302.051,1763.65)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(59,183,90);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:rgb(31,93,81);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(21,62,78);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear2" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,524.276,302.051,1004.49)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(226,226,226);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(25,65,80);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear3" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,263.844,302.051,870.864)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(226,226,226);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(25,65,80);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear4" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,524.276,302.051,1004.49)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(59,183,90);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:rgb(31,93,81);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(21,62,78);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear5" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,263.844,302.051,870.864)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(226,226,226);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(25,65,80);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear6" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,524.276,302.051,1004.49)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(59,183,90);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:rgb(31,93,81);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(21,62,78);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="_Linear7" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1922.47,0,0,524.276,302.051,1004.49)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(59,183,90);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:rgb(31,93,81);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(21,62,78);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```